# what to use on my bathroom ceiling

Tags: bathroom, ceiling

I have a home that has a leak or runs during heavy wind and rain.  Nobody can find where it leaks.  What can I use on the bathroom ceiling to keep the moisture from coming through and causing mold?

Comment: Unless you're going to seal that ceiling like the inside of a swimming pool there's nothing that will keep the water out of your bathroom. Even if you did manage to succeed at that, the water would just go somewhere else in your house and cause damage there. You need to find & fix where it's entering on the outside - there's really no other way.

Comment: "nobody can find" - I presume they checked & caulked/sealed around exhaust fan opening, right?

Comment: "Nobody can find . . . " sounds like you had some incompetents looking or someone who was unhappy with what you were willing to pay them.